# How to properly create keymaps for portuguese abnt2?

Tags: neovim

We have many language keyboard input here `/usr/share/vim/vim90/keymap/`

I use a Portuguese-br abnt2 keyboard layout on my KDE system, it works fine on Konsole, I can change the system input method. But I want to set the portuguese language to use on neovide. So I don't have to mistype all the time, e.g. comma, brackets are in different positions.

I want to go to my nvim folder `init.vim` and type: `set keymap="portuguese-br"`
I tried a modified version by me, but the neovim didn't find the file.

Answer (score 0):

I would try:

```
set keymap=portuguese-br
```